# Rails: dependent model calculation

Tags: ruby-on-rails

**Wish:** In book/show I want to see the quantity of sales OF THIS BOOK per library.

**Problem:** currenly I see the quantity of all sales per library in book/show, not only of this book

I have 3 models:

```
Library (has_many :sales, has_many :books, through: :sales)

Sale (belongs_to :library, :book) (`book_id`, `library_id`, `quantity` fields)

Book (has_many :sales, has_many :libraries, through: :sales)
```

library.rb:

```
  def books_sold_quantity
    sales.map(&:quantity).sum
  end
```

BooksController:

```
def show
    @libraries = @book.libraries
  end
```

Book/show

```
BookID:
= @book.id
Library sales
%table
  %thead
    %tr
      %th LibraryID
      %th Books sold
  %tbody
    - @libraries.each do |library|
      %tr
        %td= library.id
        %td= library.books_sold_quantity
```

Comment: `sales.where(book_id: book.id).pluck(:quantity).sum` in `books_sold_quantity` method

Comment: It gives me `undefined local variable or method 'book' for #<Library:0x007fe5a71f7c70>
Did you mean?  books`

Comment: of course you get exception, because I provide just example. You have to change your method

Answer (score 0):

Easiest option would be to go for

```
def amount_sold(book, library)
   Sale.where(book: book, library: library).sum(:quantity)
end
```

But this will create a n+1 query problem.

What is recommended here is to create a bit more advanced query that fetches the libraries in your controller. A query that fetches all libraries where this book is available, joins the sales, and sums up all sales quantity.

It would look something like this:

```
# not tested 
@book = Book.find(params[:id])
@libraries = book.libraries.joins(:sales)
                           .group(:id)
                           .select('libraries.*, SUM(sales.quantity) as quantity_sold')
```

Comment: I am a little confused.... in which model/controller do you put the query?